# Pandas, correlation between two dataframes with columns having the same name, resulting in NaN

Tags: dataframe, nan, correlation

I have two databases with the same column names and numbers. The data contains cells without data (NaN). When trying to generate the correlation with corrwith(), I only get NaN. If I correlate the same columns, I get 1. Both dataframes have the same dimensions. I checked the column names, and they are the same (in fact, I extracted them as duplicates from the same dataframe to perform the correlation). Why am I obtaining only NaN?

I have tried:

```
A.corrwith(B)
```

I have obtained:

```
PE_Ni_PCT   NaN
ML_PCT      NaN
TL_PCT      NaN
PO_H_PCT    NaN
PO_M_PCT    NaN
CP_PCT      NaN
CA_PCT      NaN
MT_PCT      NaN
BT_PCT      NaN
TA_PCT      NaN
HB_PCT      NaN
SR_PCT      NaN
CH_Mg_PCT   NaN
CH_Fe_PCT   NaN
DP_PCT      NaN
ES_PCT      NaN
QZ_PCT      NaN
OL_PCT      NaN
AB_PCT      NaN
AO_PCT      NaN
DO_PCT      NaN
CL_PCT      NaN
dtype: float64
```

A=

[image]

B=

[image]